# How to use IN opearator in Laravel WHERE clause?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am building an advanced table filter using Laravel. The client sends an array of filters to the server to apply on a model and send back the results.

On the server side I use the following code to generate an array of condition to be used in the where clause:

```
$conditionArray=array();
foreach($filtersList as $filter) {
    $whereArray[]=array($filter['Column'], $filter['Condition']), $filter['Value']);
}
$data =  User::where($conditionArray)->get();
```

This works as expected for simple operators (`=`; `<=`; `>=`; `!=`) but when I try with advanced operators (`BETWEEN`; `IN`) the query fails.

My question is how to add `IN` and `BETWEEN` to the `WHERE` clause? Is there a better approach to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel query builder has its own methods for the `in` and `between` operators. You should check the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses) for more infos.

I had a similar problem and I've resolved it with an approach a little different. Here an example:

```php
$query = MyModel::newQuery();

foreach($statements as $statement) {
    switch($statement['operator']) {
        case 'between':
          $query->whereBetween([...]);
          break;
        case 'in':
          $query->whereIn([...]);
          break;
        /* OTHER CASES */
        default:
          $query->where(/*...*/);
          break;
    }
}

$models = $query->get();
```

The result is something similar to this statement:

```php
$models = MyModel::where([...])->whereIn([...])->[...]->get();
```

Be careful anyway... This approch may cause performance issues, so try to avoid to give too much freedom with the filters selection.

Comment: This will work for all the cases thank you, But I am wondering if there is any performance difference between cascading while clauses: `MyModel::where(cond1)->where(cond2)->where(cond3)->get()` AND using array of conditions : `MyModel::where($conditionArray)->get()`

Comment: If you see the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L720) you will see that `addArrayOfWhere` method does the same. It concatenates a list of "where" clauses, but you can only perform a list of `AND` or a list of `OR` statements. There's a little more encapsulation, and that's it.